# Approximating from the interior of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

In a problem I'm working on I found myself with a point $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ lying at the boundary of a non-closed convex set $K$. I'd like to express it as as "infinite convex combination" 
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i y_i,$$
where $\lambda_i \ge 0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i=1$ and $y_i \in K$ for all indices $i$. May I do so?

Thank you.

Comment: $y$ doesn't belong to $K$? So $K$ is not closed?

Comment: @littleO: Yes, exactly. That's the problem.

Comment: I don't know whether this is helpful. But in Proposition 2.6 of http://www.mth.msu.edu/~shapiro/pubvit/downloads/numrangenotes/numrange_notes.pdf, the author proved on $\mathbb{C}$, a *finite* convex combination is the same as an *infinite convex combination*.

Comment: @HuiYu: This means that the answer to the present question is negative, as $\text{conv}_\infty(K)=\text{conv}(K)=K$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean, at least in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @HuiYu: There is something to be checked here, since $K$ of the present question is not countable. But for sure your remark strongly suggests that the claim might not be true. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry it is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The following is from [Convex series (G.J.O. Jameson)](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=3A3BC83DE67622EFF3BF6AEBBD7AA631.journals?fromPage=online&aid=2071720).

> **Definition**: A set is *CS-closed* if it contains the sum of every convergent convex series of its elements.
>
> **Example (i)**: An open convex set, $A$, is CS-closed, since $\lambda A+(1-\lambda)\overline{A}\subseteq A$ for $0<\lambda <1$.

This holds for any Hausdoff topological linear space.